# How can water create a good ground reference?

Tags: ground, grounding, panel

In the 240V Single Phase panel in my home the ground bus is tied to a water line. My concern is water flows via a non-metallic pipe from the artesian well to a holding tank. A copper line connects the tank to a plastic housed membrane filter. After the filter begins a new run of copper pipe that feeds the fixtures within the house. This section of copper pipe is where the panel ground is attached.

How can flowing water create a sufficient ground for the appliances within the house?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be migrated to DIY.SE

Comment: What does this mean: *ground bus*?

Comment: Are the copper pipes buried underground (if so, for how far) and electrically connected to each other?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson how am I supposed to distinguish which platform this should be asked on?

Comment: @Andyaka In all Electrical Panels you will find a bar (aka bus) to land ground and neutral lines on. It is this that was referencing.

Comment: @user_1818839 - no. there are no buried copper pipes.

Comment: Why was this down voted? I clearly verified the wiring in the panel and spent time searching for answers via search engines before posting here.

Comment: @StevenK7FAQ Migrating a question is a common thing that we do here, when we think that you will get better answers on another site. The mechanism for recommending migration is kind of clunky, and the default comment text begins "I'm voting to close this question because..." Don't take it personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. The water isn't a significant conductor. Most likely your panel is *providing a ground connection* to the water pipe (as required by NEC 250.104(A) in the US), not "getting its ground" from the water pipe (which it could have done if it was a metal pipe running underground for at least 10 feet), although it is possible that someone screwed up while installing the electrical service or modifying the plumbing.

If you've been looking for your ground rod, and concerned that you can't find it, seeing as how you seem to live in Arizona (I checked your callsign), it's a reasonable bet that you have an [Ufer ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ufer_ground) within your foundation.

Comment: The problem is that there is no grounding rod. That will be solved right away after I run to the parts store. Thus my seeking validation the method used was not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. That is why ground busses should be tied directly to ground rods that are buried in the earth. Of course, there are houses which use copper water lines exclusively so tying ground to them would probably be OK. It is much safer, however, to not rely on the pipes but to use ground rods expressly designed for that function. This avoids any problems down the road when the piping might be changed to some form of non-conducting material.

Comment: I wish I could accept both as the correct answer. Thank you Barry.
The problem is that there is no grounding rod. That will be solved right away after I run to the parts store. Thus my seeking validation the method used was not correct.